# How can i create a note on my webpage for iphone user that there is an app?

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, ios, css

Hello,

I started to detect which **platform** is used. And this already works:

```
   // User-Agent-String auslesen
        var UserAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        // User-Agent auf gewisse Schlüsselwörter prüfen
        if (UserAgent.search(/(iphone|ipod|opera mini|fennec|palm|blackberry|android|symbian|series60)/) > -1) {
        // mobiles Endgerät
            alert("YOU HAVE A SMARTPHONE");

        } else {
        // kein mobiles Endgerät (PC, Tablet, etc.)
            alert("YOU HAVE NO SMARTPHONE");
        }
```

But now I want to show on the **iphone** that if you have an iphone a full screen page that there is an app and you should download it. and than a button for the app and a button for "no thank you, continue to normal page".

How can i do this?

Can someone help me?

The page should be full screen and nothing else should be visible.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should follow Apple guidelines for this and use a Smart App Banner: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

If you really want an ad in fullscreen use javascript to show or create a DIV tag that cover the entire screen size. the DIV could simply be styled in absolute position with width/height at 100%

cheers